# Intermittent #error on textbox with fairly simple IIF

Tags: ms-access, textbox, ms-access-2016, iif

I've a Customer form with a tab control that holds the details for the specific items that a customer has: Ground Rent, Electricity and Garage. They may hold all 3, just Ground Rent and Electricity, or just a garage. If they don't have an item, the tab is hidden.

The issue only appears on the Garage tab: I intermittently get #ERROR in the amountdue text box. If I close down the customer and re-open them, sometimes it clears itself (with no action performed). Sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it needs me to reopen a few times before the value shows.

The box concerned is: txtActualAmountDue and the source is the following:
`=iif([tenant],[txtNet],[txtGarageCharge])`

- Tenant is a form data source Boolean (that indicates whether the Ground Rent/Electricity tabs should be shown).
- txtNet = [txtGarageCharge]-[txtVAT]
- txtVAT = [txtGarageCharge]*([txtVatPercentage]/(1+[txtVatPercentage]))

The next two are locked textboxes to make life easier

- txtGarageCharge = DLookup("[GarageCharge]","Variables", criteria that returns the current row of variables for the current date)
- txtVatPercentage = DLookup("[GarageVat]","Variables", criteria that returns the current row of variables for the current date)

The only thing else I can think of to mention is that if the customer is not a tenant, then txtNet and txtVAT are hidden. I sometimes get #Type! in txtNet and txtVat too - and obviously I also get the #Error - but not always: sometimes they're valued okay and I still get the #Error. I've commented out the load/current method lines that hides those textboxes to see if it's that, but it's made no difference.

Like I say - it's not like it happens every time: Just occasionally. Could it be to do with the order in which things are being valued/populated on the form? And once it's been populated once (the values will be the same for every customer) then it's okay? And if it's this, how do I force it to value the text boxes in the right order?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a timing issue, so try avoiding the mid calculations:

```vb
txtNet = DLookup("[GarageCharge]/(1+[GarageVat])","Variables", criteria)
txtVat = DLookup("[GarageCharge]/(1+[GarageVat])*[GarageVat]","Variables", criteria)
```

or, ultimatively:

```vb
=IIf([tenant],DLookup("[GarageCharge]/(1+[GarageVat])","Variables", criteria),DLookup("[GarageCharge]","Variables", criteria))
```

Comment: Thanks, Gustav. I've given it a go as above, but only time (and many open/closes) will tell.